# Where to set all Listeners?

Tags: android, listener, oncreate

Where to set all `Listeners` for the user interfaces?
Is it good practice to set them in `onCreate`? This looks so unstructured and strange.
Is there a better place to set them?

Comment: If you want the end user to click a button and do an action, you better initialize them `onCreate` and you can implement the rest in the `onClick(View v)`

Comment: you can use constructive alternative which i have posted among in answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

> onCreate(Bundle) is where you initialize your activity. Most
>   importantly, here you will usually call setContentView(int) with a
>   layout resource defining your UI, and using findViewById(int) to
>   retrieve the widgets in that UI that you need to interact with
>   programmatically.

When you initialize your views, they are ready to be listened. `onCreate` is good callback to set listeners. In other way you can set it in `onStart` or `onResume`, but you should understand, that its bad practice, because `onStart` and `onResume` calls every time, when user see your activity. `onCreate` calls only when Activity is initialized. It is reason, why you should use `onCreate`. Actually, good practice implement method like `initListeners()` where you can put all you listeners logic.

Good luck!

Comment: Bad answer. You should always register listeners in onStart/onResume and unregister them in onStop/onPause respectively. That's because onResume/onPause are guaranteed to be called in an activity's life cycle always but rest are not. Most people do it on onStart/onStop as it reduces multiple registers and unregisters and are mostly called, unless something goes crashing or OS kills the app

Comment: The question is "Where to set all Listeners for the user interfaces?". Why you need unregister them? You cannot play with your UI when Activity is stopped. People never unregister UI listsners like onClickListener and other like taht.

Answer (score 2):

Use `onCreate` method to set the `UI` and to get the `Widget` from `UI`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedValues) {
    // Here set the UI and get the widgets
    //set the Listeners on the widgets you are getting at the above line
}
```

And you can define a `clickListener` for the widgets and use it in `onCreate` method

```
OnClickListener someListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "widget pressed ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
};
```

and you can set the above `clickListener` to a widget which you have created in `onCreate` method

Answer (score 1):

For listeners onCreate() is good place.

Consider 2 activities A,B.

A -> B, launching 'B' Activity from 'A', if we come back from B -> A then onStart(), onResume() methods will be called again in 'A' activity and that is redundant. So it's better practice to only add listeners in onCreate() only.

And, for button listeners you can set attribute android:onClick="method_name" in xml file only.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want to avoid a mess

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                SomeActivity.this.button1_onClick(view);
            }
        });
    }

    private void button1_onClick(View view){
        ///do stubs here
    }
}
```

Comment: There are many ways to avoid even this mess. Use inner classes, let your `Activity` implement `OnClickListener`, etc. Using this way will grow unreadable when there are many more views.

Answer (score 0):

You can set onClick property for any view in xml .So now u have no need to find and set onClick in onCreate.Now u need to define public method in activity of name u mentioned in xml . This looks constructed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Activity Lifecycle, onCreate() is place where you perform basic application startup logic that should happen only once for the entire life of activity and onStart() is place where activity is visible to user and onResume() is place where user interact with activity mean touch or click.
So good place to make click listener is onResume()

Reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#lc